# Как добавить компонент по имени?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть объект `spawnedObject`. Я хочу сделать так, что бы добавлялся компонент по его типу. Например:

```
string a = "Rigidbody";
spawnedObject.AddComponent<a>();
```

Или такое Unity не по силам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string type = "Rigidbody";
spawnedObject.AddComponent(Type.GetType(type));
```